# Java function call to determine whether code is executed inside AWS Lambda or not

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a commons package that has some utils in it. For a certain method we need to check if the commons piece of code is executed inside a AWS Lambda or not, is there a simple call to determine this?

Comment: how about "System.getenv("AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME") != null" Have you checked that way?

Comment: Can you please add more details? are you trying to figure out if the called lambda function has invoked any utils from the commons package?

Comment: @JamalAlkelani I am trying to determine if the util package is used from Lambda or EC2 instances for example.

Comment: @AbdullahKhilji Where does that package lives? is it self-hosted? or lives inside AWS lambda layers?

Comment: The commons package is a normal Java package, and can be included as a dependency to any other package.

Comment: Checking environment variables, as mentioned in the first comment, is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using:

```
System.getenv("AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME") != null
```

to verify whether the runtime is within a Lambda or not.